# Save data to NSUserDefaults using Titanium

Tags: ios, titanium, nsuserdefaults, titanium-mobile

I'm currently working on a Titanium based iOS application.

In which I need to save some data (**A progress value**) to [**NSUserDefaults**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

I had done this in iOS but don't know how to do this using Titanium, I have [**searched**](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=How%20to%20save%20data%20to%20NSUserdefault%20in%20%20titanium&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&source=hp&channel=np#hl=en&client=firefox-a&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=np&sclient=psy-ab&q=save%20data%20to%20NSUserdefault%20in%20%20titanium&oq=save%20data%20to%20NSUserdefault%20in%20%20titanium&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.0.3447.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.les;..0.0...1c.I2hQHtThUCw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=bcb231deaccfe515&biw=1600&bih=717) a lot for doing this in Titanium, but couldn't find any solution.

I just need to store this single value, so no need of using a `sqlite` database, that's why I'm opting **NSUserDefaults**.

Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

> The App Properties module is used for storing application-related data
>   in property/value pairs that persist beyond application sessions and
>   device power cycles.

**Storing data:**

```
Ti.App.Properties.setString('myName', 'Midhun');
```

**Retrieving data:**

```
var name = Ti.App.Properties.getString('myName'));
```

I don't know whether it saves the data to **NSUserDefaults**, anyway it fixed my issue.

Reference : [**Titanium.App.Properties**](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties).